# Как экспортировать методы модуля?

Tags: node.js

Сам новичок в node.js , пытаюсь написать модуль но столкнулся с проблемой.. В дочернем модуле прописываю:

```
var User = require('./schema');


User.userIsExist = function(id) {
    User.findOne({id: id}), function(err, tester) {
        console.log(tester);
    }
}

module.exports = User;
```

и в главном:

```
var User = require('./model').User;

 if(User.userIsExist(userinfo.uid)) {
 // Авторизируемся
 }
```

Но на выходе получаю **TypeError: User.userIsExist is not a function**

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Вы экспортирует объект у которого нет свойства User. А при импорте вы к этому свойству обращаетесь. Правильно будет вот так

```
var user = require('./model');

if(user.userIsExist(userinfo.uid)) {
    // Авторизируемся
}
```

И лучше не давать переменным имена с большой буквы. С большой буквы обычно называют классы.